# 'scale' was not declared in this scope

Tags: servo

I am currently doing a robotic arm project. I used load cell with HX711 amplifier to detect and monitor of the objects. If the objects is less than 3kg, then the servomotor in gripper can rotate and the gripper can hold the objects. But there is an error in my coding.

[image]

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... post the actual code

Comment: #include <HX711.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// HX711 circuit wiring
const int LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN = 3;
const int LOADCELL_SCK_PIN = 2;

//Define servos
Servo servo1;//servo located at gripper

int joy1X = 0;

//variable to read analog pins
int joyVal;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);

  //declare servo connection
  servo1.attach(3);//connection of servo at gripper to PWM pin arduino
}

Comment: **Edit your question** and post the code there. You can see, can't you, that in the comment it looks pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot 'at least' to declare the global variable:

```
HX711 scale;
```

See documentation: https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/src/HX711.h

See GitHub example: https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/examples/HX711_basic_example/HX711_basic_example.ino

Comment: oh yesss got it THANK YOUUUUUU

Comment: @Nuradlin Athirah, please also thank him by marking this answer as correct, and also upvoting it if you haven't. Thank you.